# Issues reading Swedish CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV that currently have a line that says:
"skörda offra".

```
with open(location, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    idiom_lists = list(spamreader)
    print(idiom_lists[11][0])
```

The result I'm getting is skrda offra without the ö.

If I try to print just ö it have no issue.

How can I print 'skörda offra' only?

If I try:

```
print(idiom_lists[11][0].encode('utf-8').decode('ISO-8859-1'))
skÂrda offr
```

Running od:

```
od csv
0000000    020101  064542  062162  064440  020156  064164  020145  060550
0000020    062156  064440  020163  067567  072162  020150  073564  020157
0000040    067151  072040  062550  061040  071565  026150  006461  060412
0000060    061440  066557  071145  062040  020145  072554  060547  026162
0000100    031040  005015  071151  062040  020145  060555  020154  067145
0000120    070040  067545  026162  031440  005015  067556  062040  071141
0000140    071440  020165  071142  075141  020157  020141  067564  061562
0000160    071145  020054  006464  062012  071141  060440  066040  075165
0000200    020054  006465  067012  020157  062564  062556  020162  067544
0000220    062156  020145  060543  071145  066440  071157  071151  020054
0000240    006466  072012  066557  071141  062440  020154  062560  060554
0000260    026162  033440  005015  064566  064566  067564  074440  061440
0000300    066157  060545  026162  034040  005015  064566  064566  020162
0000320    067145  066040  020157  072554  060556  020054  006471  071412
0000340    071145  072440  067556  061440  071145  020157  020141  067554
0000360    064440  070572  064565  071145  060544  020054  030061  005015
0000400    062563  020162  060560  020156  067543  062555  026162  030440
0000420    006461  071412  115153  062162  020141  063157  071146  026141
0000440    030440  006462  072012  070141  060560  064040  073165  062165
0000460    020054  032061                                                
0000464
```

Comment: Have you run the input data through `od` yet?

Comment: Try decode to utf-8 like: s.decode('utf-8') for s in [your list]

Comment: @FadySaad AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams od? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_(Unix)